# How to select Text sentences from original document that are split and numbered in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a text document, i split this text document into separate sentences after full stop and displayed them, code used for this is as follows:

```
sentences = regexp(F,'\S.*?[\.\!\?]','match')
char(sentences)
```

Now i did some processing and got a selected number of sentences in the form of number like `1,2,3,4,...n` which are stored in 1D cell arrays as follows:

```
output=

out{1}= 1,2

out{2}= 2, 4

out{n}= n..
```

These 1,2,4 are the sentence numbers, i want to select and display only `sentence # 1,2 and 4` from `sentences` suppose i have `10` sentences so the output should be `3` sentences now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to select and display only the indexed sentences. For instance:

1- With a `for` loop

```
for i = 1:numel(out{1})
    fprintf('%s\n', sentences{out{1}});
end
```

2- In one line, with `cellfun`:

```
cellfun(@(x) fprintf('%s\n',x), sentences(out{1}));
```

Best,

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want to loop over uptill `n` elements istead of `out{1}` when i replace it with `out{:}` it gives error `index exceeds matrix dimentions`. for you information this `out` is `[1 cross n] cell array`

Comment: This does not correspond to what you asked in the first place ... If you want something else, please edit your question in a clear, concise and comprehensible manner.

Comment: you are absolutely rite, there was a slight misunderstanding which was my bad now this code is working perfect thanks